# wifi driver missing after installing windows 8.1

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-driver

I had `windows 10` earlier.Today i installed `windows 8.1` by erasing `windows 10`.But now i find in the `device manager` that the network adapter for wireless network and `ethernet adapter`  are missing.  Hence i am not able to use wifi.

Why did it happen and how to resolve this problem ?
I was able to use wifi earlier while using windows 10.

Comment: You need to install the wifi driver, evidently W8 did not have the proper driver for it during installation, Do a Windows update and see if it offers a wifi driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for your network drivers on another computer with internet access, put it on a usb and copy it over to your computer and install.

Answer (score 3):

Do a right-click on the Windows-Button and select Device Manager.
Under Device Management you should see your Wifi-Device with a yellow exclamation mark. Do a right-click > Properties > Details and select Hardware IDs.

Post the Hardware ID here and people will be able to tell you what Driver you need.